# Batch file (.bat) to Open and Save an Excel file

Tags: excel, batch-file, ssis

I have an Excel file on server (.xls) format. I think this is generated in some higher version of Microsoft Office Excel.

I have some SSIS packages which are failing in reading these files.

When I open and save these files as 97-2003 workbook (extension .xls) and run the SSIS packages, it executes successfully.

I can not make any changes in SSIS so I was thinking of writing a Batch (.bat) which I can schedule before my SSIS run to open and save the Excel file in required format (which I am currently doing manually) so as to make my SSIS run successfully.

How could I implement this?

Is there some better way?

Comment: what C# has to do with this?

Comment: What have you researched so far before you ask us to describe (in detail) what you need to do?

Answer (score 1):

For server task automation, give it a try with PowerShell. It's really easy to understand and use.

Resources:

[convert your ‘old’ XLS files to the new XLSX format](http://jeffwouters.nl/index.php/2013/10/powershell-function-to-convert-xls-files-to-xlsx/)

[Powershell script to convert all xls documents to xlsx in a folder recursively](https://gist.github.com/gabceb/954418)

[Excel Convert .xls to .xlsx](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/48ae02e7-9671-4498-bd27-44f6910c503a/excel-convert-xls-to-xlsx)

Answer (score 0):

Create a vbs script.

```
set xlapp = createobject("Excel.Application")
xlapp.Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\User\Documents\Super.xls"
'43 is 95/97 look up xlExcel9795 in object browser to see other options
xlapp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\User\Documents\Super.xls", 43
```

Comment: :  when I am trying to save in excel .xls format **$workbook.saveas($path, [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat]::xlExcel8)** , the open excel file gets a prompt messgae to **CONTINUE**. Until I manually Continue, my script can not proceed. What could be done to supress the prompt or click continue from powershell script itself so that entire code could process without stopping.

Comment: This comment doesn't have anything to do with the answer. This is powershell.